# Stencil buffer mask render priority for Unity UI elements

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, stencil-buffer

### Exposition.

Let's say we have some layers of UI elements:

- backlane items [blue]
- fog of war/curtain [grey]
- stencil hole (fog of war reveal) [circle]
- frontlane items (i.e. suggest bubbles) [red]

Here's what I want:
[image: expected result]

Stencil hole should reveal a part of curtain and show items behind it.
Also stencil hole has graphics on it and it should be rendered and placed in prefab above (after) the curtain.

### Problem.

Things go wrong when I try to mask the stencil hole.
I use the default Unity material as a base.

For hole: REF = 1, ALWAYS, REPLACE

For curtain: REF = 1, NOT EQUAL, REPLACE

- in natural order, a hole renders later than a curtain and has no effect (curtain rendered without a hole).

[image: backlane items not visible (blue missing)]

- if I change the render priority of the hole to **Transparent-1**, then the hole is rendered as expected. But the hole graphics go in the background and are not visible at all

[image: hole graphics not visible (circle missing)]

- if I change the priority of the curtain to **Transparent+1** then it overlaps frontlane items

[image: curtain overlaps frontlane items (red cutted)]

It's easy to change the order of elements—place the hole item before the curtain, and it would work. But I want to keep the stencil hole UI item above the curtain, closer to the frontlane - it's useful for positioning them next to each other. It also has some logic for building UI layers.

### Question.

Is it possible to apply the mask of the hole in priority **Transparent-1**, but render it in default priority?
So it goes mask → curtain → hole graphics